# Ace editor custom error checking

Tags: javascript, error-handling, syntax-error, ace-editor

I created a new language mode in my editor with a few keywords: `Ben, Tom, Brian` and operands: `AND OR ( )`. Also, I need a custom error checker. I tried to change json worker which I have been inlcuded in my mode.

Everything I need is this: `(Ben AND TOM) OR Brian` - this is correct, everything else, like undefined keywords or incorecct syntax like `BEN AND AND TOM`, or `BEN AND OR TOM`- should treat as error. Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: I have interest on this too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.
You need to create a parser for your language to detect errors and send locations to ace. There are some libraries that can help you with this. e.g http://lakhin.com/projects/papa-carlo/demo/, but even with that, it's not a trivial task

Comment: Thanks for reply. In the meantime, i edit my custom mode adding json worker client with and try to edit json parser because his code is simpler than other parser. Code is: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/json/json_parse.js. If i see good, i need to edit only: object = function ()... to adjust with my syntax. Have you any idea, i need help, please... Thanks a lot.